How to get an Exception out of an ExceptionGroup?
If I have an ExceptionGroup how do I get the Exception out of it? I happen to be using Trio.
>>> exc
>>> ExceptionGroup('Exceptions from Trio nursery', [HTTPStatusError("Client error 
'400 Bad Request' for url 'https://api.fastly.com/service/xyz/acl/xyz/entries'
\nFor more information check: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400")])


ExceptionGroup.exceptions

This is what worked for me:
except* HTTPError as exc:
    httpexps, others = exc.split(HTTPError)
    httpexp = httpexps.exceptions[0]
    if httpexp.response.status_code == 400:
        # etc etc

The except* HTTPError catches any group with the HTTPError.
The exc.split(HTTPError) splits the group into two new groups, one that is only HTTPError and one that is everything else.
The httpexps.exceptions[0] gets the first exception in that group.

In this particular case, why not do directly httpexp = exc.exceptions[0]?

@laur I was getting other non HTTPError exceptions in the exception group and only wanted to know about the HTTPError ones.

Preferably, you should not. Use Python 3.11+ and except* syntax.
Alternate solutions:
You can enumerate the member exceptions like this:
def exc_iter(exc):
    """
    iterate over all non-exceptiongroup parts of an exception(group)
    """
    if isinstance(exc, BaseExceptionGroup):
        for e in exc.exceptions:
            yield from exc_iter(e)
    else:
        yield exc

Alternately you can use this singleton to simplify your error handling:
class SingleError:
    """
    A sync+async context manager that unwraps single-element
    exception groups.
    """
    def __call__(self):
        "Singleton. Returns itself."
        return self

    @staticmethod
    def one_exc(e):
        "convert the exceptiongroup @e to a single exception"
        while isinstance(e, BaseExceptionGroup):
            if len(e.exceptions) != 1:
                break
            e = e.exceptions[0]
        return e

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    async def __aenter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, c, e, t):
        if e is None:
            return
        e = self.one_exc(e)
        raise e from None

    async def __aexit__(self, c, e, t):
        return self.__exit__(c, e, t)

SingleError = SingleError()

(The async handlers are in there so that you can group this with other async with statements without indenting too much.)
Usage:
try:
    with SingleError:
        await some_code()
except SplatError:
    print("Splat", file=sys.stderr)

Note that this will break when your code raises multiple exceptions. That happens a lot when the error handling in one part of your code depends on the part that raised the exception, or on other code that also got canceled.

Happend to just wrote exact stuff yesterday for other unrelated question so I'll copy paste here with minor modification.
Direct quote to trio Document for exactly what you asked:

To catch individual exceptions encapsulated in an exception group, the except* clause was introduced in Python 3.11 (PEP 654).
...
But what if you can’t use except* just yet? Well, for that there is the handy exceptiongroup library which lets you approximate this behavior with exception handler callbacks.


TL;DR depends on python version you use.
# >= Python 3.11
import trio

class SomeRandomError(Exception):
    pass


async def task():
    await trio.sleep(5)
    raise SomeRandomError()


async def main():
    
    # just some type hinting
    exc_group: BaseExceptionGroup
    
    try:
        async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
            for _ in range(10):
                nursery.start_soon(task)
    
    # do something with error
    except* KeyboardInterrupt as exc_group:
        print("In KeyboardInterrupt group")
        for idx, e in enumerate(exc_group.exceptions):
            print(f"Err {idx}: {type(e).__name__}")
    
    except* SomeRandomError as exc_group:
        print("In SomeRandomError group")
        for idx, e in enumerate(exc_group.exceptions):
            print(f"Err {idx} {type(e).__name__}")


trio.run(main)

# output either
# In KeyboardInterrupt group
# 0 KeyboardInterrupt

# or
# In SomeRandomError group
# Err 0 SomeRandomError

# < Python 3.11
# pip install exceptiongroup which is (sortof) backport of except
import trio
from exceptiongroup import BaseExceptionGroup, catch


class SomeRandomError(Exception):
    pass


async def task():
    await trio.sleep(5)
    raise SomeRandomError()


async def main():
    def handle_keyboard_interrupt(exc_group: BaseExceptionGroup):
        nonlocal nursery
        print("In KeyboardInterrupt group")
        for idx, e in enumerate(exc_group.exceptions):
            print(f"Err {idx}: {type(e).__name__}")
        
        nursery.cancel_scope.cancel()
    
    def handle_some_random_error(exc_group: BaseExceptionGroup):
        print("In SomeRandomError group")
        for idx, e in enumerate(exc_group.exceptions):
            print(f"Err {idx} {type(e).__name__}")
        
        nursery.cancel_scope.cancel()
    
    with catch({
        KeyboardInterrupt: handle_keyboard_interrupt,
        SomeRandomError: handle_some_random_error,
    }):
        async with trio.open_nursery() as nursery:
            for _ in range(10):
                nursery.start_soon(task)


trio.run(main)

